# How to achieve soft elevated look for icons?

Tags: sketch-app, icon, adobe-xd, figma

I am trying to figure out a way to achieve the same soft bubbly effect on icons as seen in [this design](https://dribbble.com/shots/10186148-Neumorphic-Action-Menu). Looking for resources to achieve the same using Figma, XD or Sketch.

Comment: I don't have a specific ressource for the "bumpy" effect, but this is called neumorphism. Figma has a lot of examples: https://www.figma.com/community/search?model_type=hub_files&q=neumorphism

Comment: It simply looks like an off-center radial gradient.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Amit! Can you be more specific about your problem and tell us something more regarding your efforts?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is simply two shadows applied to multiple objects. If you cranked up the contrast, it's easier to see what's happening.

The background and floating square are actually the same color. The appearance of gradients on the shapes is simple the drop shadows. There is a light drop shadow offset to the top left and a darker drop shadow to the bottom right.

This same effect is applied to the plus and other icons as they animate in and out. It's a pretty simple effect but adds a lot of interest to the design.

[image: High contrast refference]